# How to terminate a process after a certain time?

Tags: java

I was calling a `bat` file from java which contains the executing command of a file.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/k","start test.bat");
Process p = builder.start();
```

I want to terminate this process after 3s. What's the way of setting time of execution for this process?

Comment: Just use a `Timer` and destroy the process when the timer is triggered.

Comment: You can also use Cron jobs as well.

Comment: Ideally, you should use `Timer` to run the job and then use `Thread.sleep(1000L * 2); timer.cancel();` to stop it for the desired interval.

Comment: `timer.cancel();` doesn't terminate the program, it just guarantees that the ongoing task execution is the last task execution that will ever be performed by this timer. Then what's the way?

Comment: do you have any idea? @darshgohel

Comment: The question you are suggesting, doesn't contain any exact solution for terminating the process. That shows exception and guarantees that the ongoing task execution is the last task execution. Please have a look.. @AxelH

Comment: No but the timer will be used to called `p.destroy()` after a specific amount of time... Since your question is to do something after 3s, it seems correct to point you to this duplicate. Of course, you still need to connect the dots.

Comment: @fardinabir, you need to identify the solutions based on the comments, as your requirements are not much clear. In the above comments, there are a lot of hints which can actually solve your problem, but you have to identify which suits your requirement.